# Selenium WebDriver Exception: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I have tried all fixes but for some reason, exceptions are coming in my code. Please help me out. The code block is trying to automate a mass WhatsApp messaging bot.

The code was adapted from a publicly available GitHub repository.
The chrome version is updated to the newest release. I am using python 3.9 environment with the latest pip installer, updated selenium library, and the most recent chromedriver extension.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import quote

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/tmp/tarun")
#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\anirudh_bagri\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

f = open("message.txt", "r")
message = f.read()
f.close()
print('This is your message:')
print(message)
message = quote(message)

numbers = []
f = open("numbers.txt", "r")
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    if line != "":
        numbers.append(line)
f.close()
print('\nWe found ' + str(len(numbers)) + ' numbers in the file')
delay = 30

print('Once your browser opens up, make sure you sign in to web whatsapp and then press enter')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\whatsapp-bulk-messenger-master\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
input()
for number in numbers:
    if number == "":
        continue
    print('Sending message to: ' + number)
    try:
        url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + number + '&text=' + message
        driver.get(url)
        click_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , '_3M-N-')))
        click_btn.click()
        sleep(1)
        print('Message sent to: ' + number)
    except Exception:
        print('Failed to send message to ' + number)
```

This is the exception that is coming up.

```
= RESTART: C:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\whatsapp-bulk-messenger-master\automator.py =
This is your message:
Hello World,

This is my text to you from automated messaging system.

Thank You


We found 1 numbers in the file
Once your browser opens up, make sure you sign in to web whatsapp and then press enter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\whatsapp-bulk-messenger-master\automator.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\LEGION\Desktop\whatsapp-bulk-messenger-master\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This most probably happens when you run Chrome as an administrator. Try running it "not as an admin" and check once.

Just got to Chrome's properties->compatibility and change that

Comment: Just checked it, chrome is not running as an administrator, but the same error is occurring. Can you suggest some other fix?